# 503 Error while opening SharePoint app in Non-Developer site

Tags: sharepoint-addin

I have a SharePoint auto-hosted app. The app package (.app file) is added in the app catalog site. When I add the app in the developer site it works normal.

I can add the app in a Team Site as well. But when I click on it to open the app it throws "**HTTP Error 503. The service is unavailable**".

I am not sure I have any programmatic issues with the app since it is working normal in developer site. But not able to open in another site ( Team Site ).

Had anyone faced the same issue, and found a way to resolve?

Comment: Have you tried with a SharePoint hosted app? I don't know if this is related, but Microsoft will be doing away with Auto-Hosted apps at the end of next month: http://blogs.office.com/2014/05/16/update-on-autohosted-apps-preview-program/

Comment: No. My app is autohosted

Comment: What is your app doing?  Is it just the default app page that throws the error?

Comment: I am building a custom application. It has many javascript, css files and aspx pages. Although I didn't try with a fresh app. But I tried deploying the same package in another dev site, and it's running perfect there as well.